# guid/uuid in Typescript Node.js app

Tags: node.js, typescript, uuid, guid

I try to make a `uuid` (v 3.0.1) package work in Node/Typescript app, but I'm not sure what should I import and how to use it.

This is `index.d.ts` (from `@types/uuid` v 2.0.29):

```
declare namespace uuid {
    interface V1Options {
        node?: number[];
        clockseq?: number;
        msecs?: number | Date;
        nsecs?: number;
    }

    type V4Options = { random: number[] } | { rng: () => number[]; }

    interface UuidStatic {
        (options?: V4Options): string;
        (options: V4Options | null, buffer: number[], offset?: number): number[];
        (options: V4Options | null, buffer: Buffer, offset?: number): Buffer;

        v1(options?: V1Options): string;
        v1(options: V1Options | null, buffer: number[], offset?: number): number[];
        v1(options: V1Options | null, buffer: Buffer, offset?: number): Buffer;
        v4: UuidStatic;
        parse(id: string): number[];
        parse(id: string, buffer: number[], offset?: number): number[];
        parse(id: string, buffer: Buffer, offset?: number): Buffer;
        unparse(buffer: number[] | Buffer, offset?: number): string;
    }
}

declare const uuid: uuid.UuidStatic
export = uuid
```

I cant find exported class here.

For example `index.d.ts` from `angular2-uuid` looks like that:

```
export declare class UUID {
    constructor();
    static UUID(): string;
    private static pad4(num);
    private static random4();
}
```

And it's quite obvious to use:

```
let id = UUID.UUID();
```

So. How to use (import and call) `uuid`?

Comment: You have the wrong versions of types to the actual package. Make sure they match.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Yes, here is code from my project:

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
const id: string = uuid();
```

Note: to install definitions it is required to run

```
npm install --save-dev @types/uuid
```

Comment: or just `import { v4 } from 'uuid';`
That's solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work. `Error: 'v4' is not exported by node_modules/uuid/index.js`

Comment: Just re-tested on the latest version of uuid module. Everything works as expected. I'll suggest you start another question on SO.

Answer (score 13):

Per the tests:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/354cec620daccfa0ad167ba046651fb5fef69e8a/types/uuid/uuid-tests.ts

```
import uuid = require('uuid');

let uuidv4: string = uuid.v4();
```

Comment: That's works! Thanks, but...
Is there any way to use `import { } from ""` typescript style?

Comment: This works best for Typescript. Top answer was complaining about any warnings from linter

Answer (score 10):

```
import * as uuid from "uuid";
const id: string = uuid.v4();
```

Answer (score 9):

**I used uuid for my project in the following order**

*Must be installed*

```
npm i --save-dev @types/uuid
npm install uuid
```

*Using the uuid package*

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
const myuuid = uuidv4();
console.log('Your UUID is: 'myuuid);
```

Answer (score 6):

This also works for me:

```js
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4'

this.projectId = uuidv4()
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting Geshan Manandhar from his blogpost [3 efficient ways to generate UUID in Node.js](https://geshan.com.np/blog/2022/01/nodejs-uuid/) you can use a built in Nodejs package:

> **Node.js UUID with Crypto module**
>
> The crypto module was added from Node.js 14.17.0. It provides
> cryptographic functionally for multiple methods and algorithms like
> OpenSSL’s hash, HMAC, cipher. It also provides a method called
> randomUUID to generate UUID in Node.js without instaling any new NPM
> module.
>
> The method takes an options object that can have a
> `disableEntropyCache` boolean value that defaults to values. When it
> is set to true it doesn’t use the cache on the UUID generation. Below
> is a code example of Cryto module’s `randomUUID` function:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
console.log(crypto.randomUUID());
```

You can also use it this way:

```
import { randomUUID } from 'crypto';
console.log(randomUUID());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
```

if use TypeScript should install definitions:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/uuid
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

firstly install these two packages

```
npm i --save-dev @types/uuid 
npm install uuid
```

Then by using uuid package, you can easily do your job.

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
const myuuid = uuidv4();
console.log('Your UUID is: 'myuuid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even faster is to just use the builtin browser function:

```
      myuuid = self.crypto.randomUUID()
```

See Mozilla's [Crypto: randomUUID() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID)